# Ho to color specific values in scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

A sample of my data is:

```
df<-read.table (text=" No   value
1   -1.25
2   -0.9
3   0.91
4   2.39
5   1.54
6   1.87
7   -2.5
8   -1.73
9   1.26
10  -2.1

", header=TRUE)
```

The numbers outside of -2 and +2 should be coloured, let's say, red. In this example, the number are  4,7 and 10, Here is my effort :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=No, y=value)) +
  theme_bw()+geom_text(aes(label=No))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=-2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ggplot2's `aes`thetics for `color=` (and a manual color scale).

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=No, y=value)) +
  theme_bw() + geom_text(aes(label=No, color=abs(value)>2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=-2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "black", "TRUE" = "red"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with outliers colored red]

Reduction: you can combine your `geom_hline`'s if you'd like,

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=No, y=value)) +
  theme_bw() + geom_text(aes(label=No, color=abs(value)>2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(-2,2), linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("FALSE" = "black", "TRUE" = "red"))
```

In general, I prefer to use as few `geom_*`s as strictly required, relying more in ggplot2's internal grouping and aesthetic handling: it is robust, elegant, and at times more flexible when the data changes. There are certainly times when I use multiple `geom_*` calls and bespoke subsets of the data for each, so it's not a broken paradigm.

The naming of the legend is unlikely to be satisfactory in the long term. You can remove it entirely with `... + guides(color="none")`, or you can pre-process the variable in as Tom's answer demonstrates, providing a way to control the name of the group and its apparent levels.

Comment: Thank you, color=abs(value)>2 is interesting, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two `geom_text` by `subset` your data twice based on your conditions like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, value >=2 | value <= -2), 
            aes(x=No, y=value, label = No), color = "red") +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, value < 2 & value > -2), 
            aes(x=No, y=value, label = No)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=-2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Mutating a new column with the group

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = if_else(between(value, -2, 2), "Inside", "Outside")) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(No, value) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = No, col = group)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=2, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=-2, linetype="dashed", color = "red") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Inside" = "black", "Outside" = "red"))
```

[image]